# Can't run 'aws' command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I have `aws` command installed via `pip install aws`.

Whenever I type in whatever related to aws (such as `aws ecr get-login-password`),
I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Stan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/envs/rasa/bin/aws", line 5, in <module>
    from aws.main import main
  File "/Users/Stan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/envs/rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 23
    print '%(name)s: %(endpoint)s' % {
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're using a Python 2.x script with Python 3.x.

Comment: That looks like python 2.x code that you're trying to run in 3.x. Awscli from pip/pypi is no longer support as of AWSCLI v2. See install instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confusingly, the `aws` Python package is not the official one from Amazon, it's some third-party tool that doesn't work the same way. The real one is [`awscli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/).

Uninstall the `aws` package and install `awscli`:

```
pip uninstall aws
pip install awscli
```

And then your `aws` command should work.

Edit:

There is a new version called [`awscliv2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) which is **not** installable via pip, and seems to be only installable via downloading a compressed archive. It supports newer AWS features and services that the version 1 tool does not.

Comment: This is still wrong. That version stopped getting feature updates and has been in maintenance mode well over 1 year.

Comment: @jordanm - The V1 CLI [gets regular feature updates](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst); the last release was yesterday. While there may be good reasons to use the V2 CLI (including the OP's question), AWS has not stopped supporting the V1 CLI.

Answer (score 1):

The latest AWS CLI v2 is [not published to pip](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4947#issuecomment-793192340). Install instructions are in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

| pip package | official AWS? | CLI version | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n/a | Yes | v2 | Install instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) |
| awscli | Yes | v1 | Supported, but not all v2 features are being backported |
| aws | No | n/a | "Utility to manage your AWS and run Fabric against filtered set of EC2 instances" |
| awscliv2 | No | v2 | "Wrapper for AWS CLI v2." |